# class definative commands out of sync solution

Tags: php, nginx, mysqli

After about a week search I seem to find no conclusive / efficient / upto date / standard way of doing this.

The obvious solution is to run a query get the result into a variable and clear down ready for the next query - for efficiency NOT closing the connection.

This is being done in a wrapper class which has select / update / insert which in turn call a query or queries (for mysqli multi_query() ) so ideally it would be good to clear any result prior to next within query / queries to ensure it runs with no concern of what has gone before.
This does not seem possible as some solutions need a result set.

Currently the select / update / insert call:

```
 private function queryclearup($dataresource) {
        //clear up if required
        switch ($this->dbtype) {
             case "mysqli":
                    @mysqli_next_result($this->connection);
                    @mysqli_free_result($dataresource); //clear result to avoid out of sync issues
                    break;
        }
 }
```

after dealing with the result set - for example converting to a data array in the case of select, or just logging an error in the case of update / insert.

Still this problem persists with some (update), but not others (select / insert).

```
 public function select($query, $args = array()) {
        $this->loghelper->write("SQL Select\n" . $query);
        $args = _PHP::array_defaults($args, array(
                                "pk" => null
        ));
        $data_table = array();
        $errors = null;
        $query = utf8_decode($query);
        switch ($this->dbtype) {
             case "mysqli":
                    $dbdata = $this->query($query);
                    $data_table = $this->resourceToDataTable($dbdata, $args);
                    break;
        }
        return $data_table;
 }
```

Then

```
private function resourceToDataTable($dataresource, $args = array()) {
            $data_table = array();
            if (gettype($dataresource) == "resource" || gettype($dataresource) == "object") {
                 do {
                        switch ($this->dbtype) {
                             case "mysqli":
                                    $row = $dataresource->fetch_assoc();
                                    break;
                        }
                        if ($row) {
                             array_push($data_table, $row);
                        }
                 } while ($row);
                 if (!empty($args["pk"])) {
                        $pktable = array();
                        foreach ($data_table as $d) {
                             if (!array_key_exists($args["pk"], $pktable)) {
                                    $pktable[$d[$args["pk"]]] = $d;
                             }
                        }
                        $data_table = $pktable;
                 }
            }
            $this->queryclearup($dataresource);
            return $data_table;
     }
```

Comment: you are moving only to a next result. What if there are others?

Comment: They have already been looped thru if it's a select the others should just be boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be whats required

```
  private function queryclearup($dataresource) {
    //clear up if required
    switch ($this->db["contype"]) {
      case "mysqli":
        while ($dump = @mysqli_next_result($this->connection)) {
          $donothing = 1;
        }
        @mysqli_free_result($dataresource); //clear result to avoid out of sync issues
        break;
    }
  }
```